# Knockout.js template binding - call a function of tinyMCE to load preview

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, tinymce, preview, knockout-templating

I am using KO.JS and building a html template.

I want to display TinyMCE Preview by calling its preview command in the html binding.

In general, this is how we render the preview for tinymce on an external button click :

```
var preview = function (divName) {
var ID = divName 
    var myEditor = tinyMCE.editors["divName"];
    myEditor.execCommand("mcePreview");
}
```

Note: I have multiple DIVs with the TinyMCE RTE, so passing divName as parameter.

**My Problem Area:**

I want to render the preview in a DIV using the above function.
I am trying to call the same command in my Template Script.

Below is my template code :

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmplPreviewModal">

// Lots of other bindings go here //

// Below code should bind Tiny MCE RTE Preview to our DIV // 

<div data-bind="html : {'tinymce.get('id': 'myTxtArea').execCommand('mcePreview'); '} "></div>

 </script>
```

This code doesnt work, also throws error as shown in below screenshot  :

[image]

Is it not possible to write my JS code within the template binding?

I even tried calling the JS Function `preview` as shown below:

[image]

Please suggest

Comment: remove the ' from the second red rectangular

Comment: <div data-bind="html : {'tinymce.get('id': 'myTxtArea').execCommand('mcePreview'); } " </div> This is also throwing error

Answer (score 0):

You can use init function of your viewmodel like jquery plugin:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    //blah
    self.init = function() {
        tinyMCE.init({
            setup: function(ed) {
                ed.onChange.add(function(ed, l) {
                    self.preview(tinymce.get('id': 'myTxtArea').getContent());
                });
            };
        });
    };
    self.preview = ko.observable();
};


var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
vm.init();
<div data-bind="html : preview "></div>
```

[How to use jQuery in a Knockout.js Template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955862/how-to-use-jquery-in-a-knockout-js-template)

Or you can use plugin tinymce-knockout-binding

https://github.com/michaelpapworth/tinymce-knockout-binding

Comment: If I use the init function, can you please tell me how to bind the value to the div? For ex here in the html binding :  <div data-bind="html:  ----------------------"</div>

Comment: I have change my answer, you want get the html and set in DIV ? For show the preview ?

Comment: Yes, I have created a template in KO.JS. This template will render a preview. It will contain many TinyMCE RTEs and also some other information like dropdown selected values, titles etc. I am able to display everything from my view model except TinyMCE RTE Preview.

Answer (score 0):

`"html : {'tinymce.get('id': 'myTxtArea').execCommand('mcePreview'); '} "` is syntactic nonsense. The right-hand side should be a string value, but it's got curlies like it's a hash, but instead of a key, it has a string wrapping a function call that itself has single quotes.

My simplest guess is that the curlies, the outermost single quotes, and the semicolon don't belong, (Update: also the colon should be a comma) so you want

`"html : tinymce.get('id', 'myTxtArea').execCommand('mcePreview')"`

That is correct if the result of that `execCommand` is an HTML string. But I suspect that TinyMCE Preview itself wants to manipulate the DOM, which would mean you need a custom binding handler for it.

Comment: Thank You for correcting me here. I have used the statement suggested by you. Still getting an error : uncaught SyntaxError: Unable to process binding "template: function (){return { name:'tmplPreviewModal'} }"
Message: Unable to parse bindings.
Bindings value: html : tinymce.get('id': 'myTxtArea').execCommand('mcePreview')

Comment: Forgot about the colon in the `get()` call. Is that supposed to be a comma?